# Android action automatic run

Tags: android, action, launch

I'm asked that on [Xamarin](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/264550?), but I ask it in here too.

So, How can I run Android activity called `redirecti` automatically when my app is launched (without button click)?
I'm tried timers, but them don't work. Maybe I'm coded them wrong.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void redirecti(View view) {
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.package");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to redirect app user to another app (it's now `com.app.package`).
I'm using Java and Android Studio.
I'm beginner in Java and Android coding.
Please help me!

Best regards

Teemu or Kuvaaja

Comment: Call `redirecti()` in `onCreate()`?

Comment: How? Can you write code?

Comment: I don't need code. I'm solved that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@earthw0rmjim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3363481/earthw0rmjim) about your comment! I'm solved my problem now (because now I understand comment)! My code is now:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.package");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}

public void redirecti(View view) {
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.package");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}
}
```

Need I `redirecti` action?